# Zend page cache storing empty string

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, memcached

We use zend page cache on our website to improve performance. We use memcached as the cache backend.

THE PROBLEM:
The cache works, ie you load a page for the first time and it will store it in the cache. You reload the page and retrieve it from the cache and that works ok, for a while. SOMEHOW, randomly, the homepage cache becomes empty (appears to ONLY affect the home page so far). It is not possible for the actual homepage to have served no content as far as I know (unless a HEAD request could be cached). So I'm not sure how its overwriting the cache. The cache ID is the same, but the contents of the cache is 0 bytes. Has anyone experienced this before?

We never had this problem until we swapped to a load balanced setup - we have 2 load balances in front of 2 web servers and it load balances between them, with memcached on one server. Turning off the secondary web server makes no difference, it still messes up.

Comment: Sounds like a long story! It's hard to read.. :)

Comment: It is a long story :( I don't quite know how to explain it apart from page cache randomly creates an empty cache and serves it, as the the website loaded absolutely nothing and it cached that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, finally. Went through many, many ways to get this working.. finally!

Cliffs: Zend Page Cache will cache HEAD requests to a page with the same cache id as a user GET request. The problem is, the `HEAD` request is always going to have an empty response body.

I added some debugging code to just after `$cache->start()` in my Bootstrap.php to log some details about what pages were being accessed, what protocol, host, response code, user agent and IP.

```
$start = $cache->start();
$start = $start === false ? 'false' : 'true';
$uri = $this->ns->https ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$uri = $uri . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$debug = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . "\t".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\t".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\tCache: $start\tUri: $uri";
$debug .= "\t " . http_response_code() . "\t";
$debug .= "\t " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
file_put_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'/logs/cachestartresult.log', $debug."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

I added this to `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page` just before the `die()` in `start()` to indicate that its cached, but there's no data.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$debug = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . "\t".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\t".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\tCache: true (dieing".(empty($data) ? " - data is but cache exists":"").")\tUri: $uri";
$debug .= "\t " . http_response_code() . "\t";
file_put_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'/logs/cachestartresult.log', $debug."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

I added this before the `ob_start()` in the `start()` function:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$debug = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . "\t".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\t".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\tCache: new cache\tUri: $uri";
$debug .= "\t " . http_response_code() . "\t";
file_put_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'/logs/cachestartresult.log', $debug."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

So basically I found the output was:
I loaded a page, it cached fine. If I cleared the cache, and a HEAD request was performed before it was cached again (say, by Newrelic or pingdom etc), it would cache the page as empty and would not work again until I cleaned the cache.

Now my only concern is how the cache is emptying itself automatically. But yay! I blocked it off by only starting cache of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "Head"`

Comment: Cache was emptying itself from default expire time of the cache. We set it to null to make it not expire. BUT its still occasionally messing up when Baidu spider and Yandex spider crawl the page >_<